# Characterization of summable families

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Could somenone help me with to prove the following result?

**If $C=\{\lambda\in{\Lambda}:x_\lambda\neq{0}\}$ is countable and for every bijective mapping $\tau:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow{C}$ $\sum_{n\geq{1}}x_{\tau(n)}$ is a convergent serie, then $\{x_\lambda:\lambda\in{\Lambda}\}$ is a summable family.**

I have proved the contrary implication, but I dont't know how to prove this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: Where?, I have not found it yet